# How to get the outer parent controller from inside an ember component?

Tags: ember.js

Currently I'm passing a custom keyword into the component like so (as I loop over each model in my array controller)

```
{{#each thing in controller}}
  {{my-thing foo=controller}}
{{/each}}
```

Then inside my component I can add a custom attributeBindings and bind to "foo" but I'd like to think I can get access to the parent controller (from inside the component itself)

How else can I get this from inside the component in ember 1.8+ ?

Comment: Have you tried some like this.get('parentView'); or you may need this.get('parentView.parentView'); This should get you access to the parent controller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [`targetObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_targetObject):

> If the component is currently inserted into the DOM of a parent view, this property will point to the controller of the parent view.

In the Component, you can use `this.get('targetObject');` to get the Controller of the parent view.

Comment: As latest Ember release(2.8), `targetObject` will be deprecated [ref](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/14168)

Comment: Guys what about `_targetObject` (starts with underscore)? We are using it everywhere. :(